# Having a hard time finding a Java mp3 player(api) with a lot of functionality

Tags: java, api, mp3, media-player

I've been looking at different API's (recently I've used JLayer), and I can't seem to find one with as much functionality as I'm looking for.

I have an assignment to make a media player, that plays MP3 files(was recommended that we use some api). I know how to do the GUI, storing the files into playlists, and other things. The thing that I need help with is the playing the music part.

I don't know if there is an API that fills all of my needs, but this is my check list.
Needs to be able to:

- Play an mp3 file
- Pause and start again
- Able to set the volume
- Able to skip to a certain place in a song
- Would be nice to have the length of the song

I think that is essentially my list of things I'd like to see in an API, I've just been having a hard time finding one.

Any suggestions would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gstreamer - http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/ should help you.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this one. Seems like there is a lot of functionality in there, thanks!